# Why is jQuery mouseover not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want it so when you hover over any one of the two images, it will trigger the corresponding `<figcaption>`.  I have it so when you hover over ANY of the two images, it will only hide the first one.  I'm not good with jQuery but I'm positive there is a way of doing it.

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gxQkQ/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's have to be unique.

Try this:

```
    $('img').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).next().slideUp(200);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).next().slideDown(200);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/gxQkQ/4/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).find('figcaption')` to get current hovered figcaption,

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#q-omega').on('click', function () {
        $('#search-bar').fadeToggle(400);
    });
    $('figure').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('figcaption').slideUp(200);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('figcaption').slideDown(200);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gxQkQ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

First: ID of an element must be unique so use class/element selector to group them

So

```
<figcaption class="caption">
```

then

```
$('figure').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(200);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pq8c6/)